# Paypal dialog in android

Tags: android, paypal

I am using PayPal MPL library in our App. PayPal login popup dialog in our app show fine in Samsung tablet and Samsung s duos but when I open our app in Samsung s4 then PayPal login dialog show in little small dialog. How I resolve this problem any idea?

Comment: Hii... have you used Paypal lib so is there any class with the name PaypalDialog?

Comment: I am using PayPal_MPL.jar lib in our project

Comment: Hey I have the same issue, I notice when you specify targetSdkVersion in manifest file above 3 then the dialog become smaller. I am still trying to find the way to solve it out...

Comment: any one found solution for this...